# Yellow spots on leaves of my spices

Tags: plant-health, rosemary

Does somebody comes up with an idea why my spices got those lighter spots on their leaves:

[image]

IMO it comes from airpolution, but can't proof it.

Comment: Have you ever fertilized these plants?  The color is off for the rosemary as well as the little ground cover.  Plants struggling to make food for themselves are weakened and susceptible to insects, disease a healthy plant could normally handle.  A little balanced all purpose fertilizer and a pruning, a heading taking off a good third of your rosemary.  Manual 2 handed, hedging shears? Try working towards the plant being wider than tall 2:1, for this herb 2:1 1/2.  And Bamboo's recommendations for Neem spray.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely leafhopper damage, specifically what's known as Sage and Ligurian Leafhoppers - they're usually under the leaves, small and unless you look closely, you may not actually see them. It isn't just rosemary that's affected, other aromatic/herb plants in the Lamiaceae family are subject to the same thing, plants like sage, lavender, mint and so on.

Because many of these plants are grown for culinary use, and the infestation of leafhoppers is largely unlikely to kill the plant, their presence if often just tolerated. You could try neem spray, but use of systemic insecticides is not recommended if you want to use the plant in food. More info here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=871